# RegEx: Match a word with exactly one occurrence of a specified character at the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to detect words starting with `$` but ignore words starting with `$$` because I want to give the user a way to escape that character.

I have tried many things, but the nearer I got was this: `[^\$]\$\w+`

It matches occurrences like `The side bar $$includes a| $Cheatsheet|, full` with the white space at the beginning of the word `$Cheatsheet` included. It should match the word `$Cheatsheet` only, without the space.

How can I do it? Any ideas?

Comment: What is the language or tool you plan to use that regex in? This sounds like something that can be solved using lookbehinds, but they aren't available in all implementations.

Comment: @SebastianProske It's JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you tried `[^\$]\$\w+` will match not a dollar sign followed by a dollar sign and one or more times a word character. That would match for example `a$Cheatsheet` or `$Cheatsheet` with a leading space. Note that you don't have to escape the dollar sign in the character class.

If [negative lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are supported, to match a word that does not start with a dollar sign you could use:

`(?<!\$)\$\w+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kxyat3/1/)

Without a lookbehind you could match what you don't want and capture what you do want in a capturing group.

`\${2}\w+|(\$\w+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9pHUKp/1)

If the dollar sign can also not be in the middle of the word you could use:

`\S(?:\$+\w+)+\$?|(\$\w+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FYc4dD/1/)

Comment: without lookbehind version matches `aaa$bbb`

Comment: @Aprillion That is correct. I have updated my answer and added a regex that does not capture the word in a group when there is a dollar sign in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Since negative lookbehinds are NOT yet supported in all JavaScript engines (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind), you can start with your regex and introduce a match group:

```
[^\$](\$\w+)
```

then, to exclude `aaa$bbb`, it is possible to use:

```
\s(\$\w+)
```

**edit**: and to match at the beginning or after punctuation:

```
(?:^|[^$\w])(\$\w+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/3cW5oY/2

Comment: `[^\$](\$\w+)` and `\s(\$\w+)` won't match at the start of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so what? no one wanted to match at the start of the string

Comment: The first comment is obsolete after the  question edit. Now, this answer is just wrong.

Comment: please explain `just wrong`... it's the only version that actually did not match `aaa$bbb` at the time of writing ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I'm sure other answers will be fixed, but I do not understand your comment what is "just wrong"...

Comment: [Your solution does not match at the start and after punctuation](https://regex101.com/r/6pPehx/1).

Answer (score 0):

You want to escape a `$` with `$`. That means, you need

```
/(?:^|[^$])(?:\${2})*\B(\$\w+)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v4kBNS/2).

**Details**

- `(?:^|[^$])` - start of string or any char but `$`
- `(?:\${2})*` - 0 or more repetitions of double dollar (this is required to avoid matching literal dollars)
- `\B` - requires start of string or non-word char before the next `$`
- `(\$\w+)` - Group 1: a `$` and then 1+ word chars.

JS demo:

```js
var s = "The $side bar $$includes a| $Cheatsheet|, $$$$full aaa$side";
var res = [], m;
var rx = /(?:^|[^$])(?:\${2})*\B(\$\w+)/g;
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: this matches `aaa$side`

Comment: @Aprillion Now, it does not. It is the least issue there could be actually.

Comment: the question currently starts with `detect words starting with $`. I would say not matching `$` in the middle of a word is an important negative test case.